# php- convert two dimentional array to in single dimentional array

Tags: php, arrays

I am reading my css folder and received the below array.

```
Array
(
    [FormValidation] => Array
        (
            [0] => formValidation.css
        )

    [0] => bootstrap-theme.css
    [1] => bootstrap-theme.min.css
    [2] => bootstrap.css
    [3] => bootstrap.min.css
    [4] => component.css
    [5] => custom.css
    [6] => custom_11_1_backup.css
    [7] => datepicker.css
    [8] => dropkick.css
    [9] => easy-responsive-tabs.css
    [10] => jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.css
    [11] => jquery.fileupload.css
    [12] => jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css
    [13] => jquery.noty.css
    [14] => noty_theme_default.css
    [15] => owl.carousel.css
    [16] => owl.theme.css
    [17] => owl.theme.default.min.css
    [18] => print_invoice.css
    [slider] => Array
        (
            [0] => AjaxLoader.gif
            [1] => owl.theme.css
        )

    [19] => validationEngine.jquery.css
)
```

Now I want these like in below format.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [path] => css/FormValidation/formValidation.css
            [name] => formValidation.css
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [path] => css/bootstrap-theme.css
            [name] => bootstrap-theme.css
        )
)
```

I dont know how to handle the recursive array for the folders.

Comment: Uh, you're not converting to a single dimension. The second array is as multi-dimensional as the first.

Comment: Sorry but I want data in that format and not getting any solution for that.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Where did you fail?

Comment: I used below code.

  foreach ($cdir as $key => $value) {
                    $css_folder = $path;
                        if (is_array($value)) {
                            $css_folder = $path . $key.'/';
                            $css_insert   =   BasicFunctions::getFilePath($cdir[$key],$css_folder,$css_insert);
                             } else {
                           $css_insert[]['path'] = $css_folder.$value;
                         }
                  }
                return $css_insert;
But some indexes are overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's a solution with a recursive call of a function.

### Code

```
    <?php
        $data = array(
            'FormValidation' => array (
                   0 => 'formValidation.css'
            ),
            0 => 'bootstrap-theme.css',
            1 => 'bootstrap-theme.min.css',
            2 => 'bootstrap.css',
            3 => 'bootstrap.min.css',
            4 => 'component.css',
            5 => 'custom.css',
            'slider' => array (
                0 => 'AjaxLoader.gif',
                1 => 'owl.theme.css',
            ),
            19 => 'validationEngine.jquery.css',
        );

        $initpath = 'css';
        echo '<b>INPUT</b><pre>'; var_dump($data); echo '</pre>';    // for testing purpose only
        $result = extractStyleSheets($data, $initpath);
        echo '<b>RESULT</b><pre>'; var_dump($result); echo '</pre>'; // for testing purpose only

        function extractStyleSheets($input,$path='') {
            $result = array();
            $success = true;
            foreach($input as $key => $item) {
                if (is_array($item)) { // It's an array, so we have a sub-level
                    // Recursive call of function and merging the arrays
                    $result = array_merge(
                        $result, 
                        extractStyleSheets($item,$path . (empty($path) ? '' : '/') . $key)
                    );
                } else {
                    // For style sheets only do
                    if (preg_match('/(.*?\.css)/i', $item, $regs)) {
                        // Push a sub-array to the result array
                        $result[] = array(
                            'path' => $path . '/' . $item,
                            'name' => $item
                            );
                    }
                }
            }
            return $result;
        }
    ?>
```

### Result

> ```
> array(9) {
>     [0]=> array(2) { 
>         ["path"]=> string(37) "css/FormValidation/formValidation.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(18) "formValidation.css"
>     }
>     [1]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(23) "css/bootstrap-theme.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(19) "bootstrap-theme.css"
>     }
>     [2]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(27) "css/bootstrap-theme.min.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(23) "bootstrap-theme.min.css"
>     }
>     [3]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(17) "css/bootstrap.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(13) "bootstrap.css"
>     }
>     [4]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(21) "css/bootstrap.min.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(17) "bootstrap.min.css"
>     }
>     [5]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(17) "css/component.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(13) "component.css"
>     }
>     [6]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(14) "css/custom.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(10) "custom.css"
>     }    
>     [7]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(24) "css/slider/owl.theme.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(13) "owl.theme.css"
>     }
>     [8]=> array(2) {
>         ["path"]=> string(31) "css/validationEngine.jquery.css"
>         ["name"]=> string(27) "validationEngine.jquery.css"
>     }
> }
> ```